# How do i rotate an image without using anything under "transform" in the processing reference?

Tags: rotation, processing

For my assignment i have an 800,800 window with a face and i need to make it rotate when i press 'r'. I have previously done this by making it an image and using the rotate() function but my lecturer says that this isn't allowed. is there any way that this can be done?

This is the code for the face

```java
void draw() {
  stroke(255,0,0);
  fill(255,0,0);
  background(255);
  ellipse(400,headYpos,100,100); //head  
  stroke(0);
  fill(255);
  ellipse(375,rightEyeYPos,20,20); //right eye
  ellipse(425,leftEyeYPos,20,20); //left eye
  ellipse(400,mouthYpos,75,25); //mouth
  fill(0,255,0);
  ellipse(400,noseYpos,20,20); //nose  
  stroke(0);
  fill(0);
  ellipse(375, rightPupilPos, 5,5); //left pupil
  ellipse(425, leftPupilPos, 5,5); //right pupil
}
```

There is also a keyPressed() function but there is nothing in it so far as i have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're supposed to store the different positions of each shape for each rotation and use that.

You could just use a bunch of [variables](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/creating-variables), or you could use something more complicated like [arrays](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/arrays) or even [classes](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/creating-classes).